# What effect does orange juice have when used in dough?

Tags: food-science, dough, juice, middle-eastern-cuisine

I was following a recipe to make some Middle Eastern inspired Olive bread, and the recipe called for a cup of orange juice in the dough.

I was intrigued by this as I had not seen it before.

What effect would the orange juice have when use in the dough? Are there any specific reasons to use orange juice in dough?

Here is the rest of the recipe for the dough:

- 4 cups flour
- 1 cup oil
- 1 cup orange juice
- 1 egg
- 2 tsp. baking powder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reasons for adding orange juice:

- The first is for flavor.
- The second is to act as an acid.

  Although in this particular case,the acid is already in the baking powder. All baking powder needs to act as a leavening agent is some kind of liquid. Unless you meant baking soda, in which case an acid is necessary for leavening.
- The third is to inhibit mold growth.

  The real reason vitamin C is added is as a dough enhancer, not for gluten development. Since this is a quick bread (no yeast), gluten development is not a main concern.
- The fourth reason for the orange juice is to make a tender crumb.

  Because of the fructose found naturally in it. Sugars are added to baked goods as a tenderizing agent.

This recipe sounds yummy!

Comment: +1, albeit I wouldn't say flavor is in first place, but second after orange juice being acid.

Answer (score 5):

In her book, [Bakewise](http://books.google.com/books?id=b-iwjIb2RxwC&lpg=PA480&dq=cookwise%20vitamin%20C%20gluten&pg=PA480#v=onepage&q&f=false), Shirley Corriher writes that vitamin C strengthens gluten. Many "dough enhancers" feature vitamin C as a large component.

Of course orange juice also tastes good which is probably why it was included in your recipe.

Answer (score 1):

A little lemon- or orange juice in the dough affects the gluten well and gives a better rising. [try this site](http://www.clausmeyer.dk/en/grupe___meyer_flour/bread_recipes.html)

Comment: Any idea of why that is? I guess it lowers the pH, but then any acid would do, right?

Comment: The recipe that included the orange juice is using significantly less than the OP's 1 cup.

Comment: I added the rest of the recipe for the dough to the question. It turns out it was an entire cup.

Comment: Can you say  why? Not quite worth a +1, sorry...